# how to add a button on right of a textview

Tags: android, xml, android-relativelayout, android-framelayout

i want to add a button on right of a textview and if textview grows,button would be still there.i used FrameLayout or RelativeLayout but they didn't work,please help me.
a layout like this image http://www.8pic.ir/images/97364937705465965477.png

Comment: Please post your layout

Answer (score 0):

Try with `LinearLayout` by giving `orientation` as `horizontal`.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text="your text"
             />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text="button" />

       </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i tried this before but it's not work.i want a layout like this image http://www.8pic.ir/images/97364937705465965477.png

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible directly and it is not good practice also for Android development. Though if it is your requirement, then you can count lines and number of character in last line at run time and decide the position of your button by using either frame or relative layout.